# Select div just above the selected webelement in Selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-ide

I have the following usecase :

```
<div style="some property">
<div style="some property">
<div style="some property">
<div style="some property">
<div>
<div> 
... n times (these number of divs are dynamic)
<div> selected element </div>
</div>
</div>
<div style="some property">
<div style="some property">
<div style="some property">
```

I have the selected element in selenium. I have to traverse up from that element and select the first div which satisfy certain css property. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Which selected element ? Please post the code trials so someone can help you out in this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
Option 1

```
//*[@id='something']/ancestor::div
```

Option 2

```
//*[@id='something']/preceding::div
```

collect these element in list and traverse through loop.